# Angular Provider - Encapsulate it inside his own module only

Tags: angular

I'm working on a CoreFramework and we have some services that we would like to keep private to our module. Is it possible?

I didn't find anything about keeping Services private to other modules that inject our module.

Comment: Don't export them from module main file. The one cannot inject something the one cannot import. This depends on your intentions, of course, because there is no privacy in JS.

Answer (score 0):

Any module or component can import and inject a service located in others module.

The export property in NgModule has no effect to service. At really, according angular documentation, the export property is applied to declarations: component, directive, and pipe classes.

A module or component can import directly the file and instantiate the exported class or inject it.

https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-api